# How to substitute columns more efficiently?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 dataframes `df1` and `df2` in which `df1` contains only 0. Let's call the sets of columns in `df1` and `df2` by `col1` and `col2` respectively. For each column name in `col2`, if it belongs to `col1`, I will replace the corresponding column in `df1` by its counterpart in `df2`.

In my example, `df1` is

[image]

and `df2` is

[image]

Then my desired result is

[image]

To do so, I use loop through each column name in `col2`. However, Python returns a warning

> PerformanceWarning: DataFrame is highly fragmented.  This is usually the result of calling `frame.insert` many times, which has poor performance.  Consider joining all columns at once using pd.concat(axis=1) instead.  To get a de-fragmented frame, use `newframe = frame.copy()`

Could you elaborate on a more efficient method?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]),
                   columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])

df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[0, -2, 3], [4, 5, -6]]),
                   columns=['a', 'c', 'd'])

for c in df2.columns:
    if c in df1.columns:
        df1[c] = df2[c]
```

Comment: The `-4` at `(a, 1)` in the desired result should be just `4`, right?

Comment: @orlp You're right!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [**`DataFrame.update`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.update.html) to update existing dataframe. Since, `df2` has extra columns that are not in `df1` `DataFrame.update` adds them too. To update only correct columns/index we can use [**`pd.Index.intersection`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.intersection.html) here.

```
cols = df2.columns.intersection(df1.columns)
idx  = df2.index.intersection(df1.index)
df1.update(df2.loc[idx, cols])

print(df1)
   a  b  c
0  0  0 -2
1  4  0  5
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe by replacing

```
df1[c] = df2[c]
```

with

```
df1[c][:] = df2[c]
```

you can ensure that you're overwriting the column in-place, rather than inserting a new column with the same name and removing the original one. This should prevent fragmentation. This only works if all your data has the same type though.